# Avoid music playback getting streamed by Discord?

Tags: macos, audio, discord

I'm using the Discord app on macOS to audio-chat with people using headphones, but they've told me they listen to the music I'm listening on Youtube (on Safari) when I speak.

**How can I avoid my audio playback stream getting sent through the app?**

It is not the mic picking up the sound from the air since I'm using headphones. The sound streams seem to be getting mixed or something.

Here's [a screen recording of my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6uZh.jpg). You can see on Discord's input sensibility bar how the level increases while playing a video.

Interestingly enough, you can hear my voice - but not the audio of the video. That's what I would expect to happen to my friends - but it's not what they're getting.

---

I've switched to using Discord from a Chrome tab instead of the app, and it now seems to work as expected. I'm not sure what it is that the macOS app is doing - but it seems to be done in purpose.

---

It's now picking up sound from a WhatsApp Desktop video that I'm playing

Comment: Can your friends hear you through the mic? Do you have your music too loud? It's highly unlikely both inputs are mixed.

Comment: They can hear me and the music. I thought I had installed something like [SoundFlower](https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/), but it seems it's not here. And Discord clearly has `External Microphone` set as the input device.

Comment: @CaldeiraG it seems it's something the macOS app does - using Discord via the Browser, the issue doesn't happen.